# The map that sends $A$ to its greatest eigenvalue is continuous.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, continuity

> The map $f:S_n(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(M)$ is the greatest eigenvalue of $M$ is continuous ($S_n(\mathbb R)$ is the set of symmetric matrices)

I need to prove this result in order to solve a broader problem.

I never feel comfortable when proving continuity of such maps.

I'd say that the map that takes $M$ to $\chi_M$ is continuous (why?), and the map that sends a real polynomial with only real roots $Q$ to its greatest root is continuous (why again?).

For the first question, I may argue that the coefficients of $\chi_M$ are polynomials in the coefficients of $M$ (doesn't sound very rigorous though)...

---

The original problem is the following

> Let $\delta$ and $M$ be positive reals. Let $S_n(\mathbb R)^{++}$ denote the set of real positive definite matrices.
>
> Prove the set $\{ A\in S_n(\mathbb R)^{++} | \det A \geq \delta \;\;\text{and}\; \; sp(A)\subset [0,M]\}$ is compact.

Comment: What is the norm you use in $M_n(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @enzotib It doesn't matter since it's finite dimensional.

Comment: The second part is already answered [Here](math.stackexchange.com/questions/134412/a-problem-to-prove-a-map-is-continuous) ..

Comment: Don't you need to restrict the domain to symmetric matrices to guarantee real eigenvalues?

Comment: @seaturtles you're a mind-reader!

Comment: Do you consider only real eigenvalues? Then your map is not defined everywhere. Or maybe you mean the greatest absolute value among a eigenvalues?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/63196/8157

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a normed space, the norm map $v \in V \mapsto \|v\| \in \mathbb R$ is continuous.

The spectral norm of a matrix $A$ is given by its largest singular value, which is also the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $AA^*$.

For real symmetric matrices, $AA^*=A^2$ and so the spectral norm of $A$ is largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Thus the map $A \mapsto \|A\|_2=\lambda_{max}(A)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can use Rouché's Theorem in complex analysis to prove that the (complex) roots of a *complex* polynomial vary continuously with the coefficients of the polynomial.