# Quotient space of $\Bbb C^n$ obtained by action of $S_n$

Tags: symmetric-groups, group-actions

Consider the action of $S_n$ on $\mathbb{C^n}$ given by:
$$\sigma(x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_n) = (x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)}, \cdots,x_{\sigma(n)}).$$

What is the quotient space of $\mathbb{C^n}$ obtained by the action of $S_n$?

I considered the case $n =2$ and tried thinking of the problem geometrically, but I didn't get far.

In this case equivalence classes look like $\{(x_1,x_2),(x_2,x_1)\}$ because action is by $S_2$

Comment: This is not an action. You need $\sigma^{-1}$'s on the RHS.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Although I prefer left actions, I wouldn't go so far as to call a right action "not an action".

Comment: @AndreasBlass: but would you go so far as writing a right action on the left?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Not while I'm awake.

Answer (score 7):

The quotient is actually $\mathbb{C}^n$ indeed. This is really an algebraic corollary and the geometric intuition here wouldn't be that helpful, mainly because we are talking about the *homeomorphism* type of the quotient, so we have quite a lot of flexibility.

For that matter, we are in *complex* space, where the hyperplane of a reflection has topological codimension 2, so taking the quotient doesn't create boundaries... (the action of $S_2$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ is equivalent to the action $x\rightarrow -x$ on $\mathbb{C}$, the quotient of which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ in the same way $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ (the circle).

Let me give a description of the quotient and try and persuade you that it is $\mathbb{C}^n$, and then we'll talk about the algebra behind this:

Consider the map $$\begin{alignat*}{1} f:\mathbb{C}^n&\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^n \\ (x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) &\longrightarrow \big( e_1({\bf x}),\cdots,e_n({\bf x})\big) \end{alignat*}$$
where ${\bf x}=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $e_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ elementary symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables.

Now, $f$ is clearly continuous, so if I convince you that the preimages $f^{-1}({\bf z})$ are exactly the orbits $S_n\cdot {\bf x}$, then you should believe me that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is indeed (homeomorphic to) the topological quotient $S_n\backslash \mathbb{C}^n$.

What is the preimage $f^{-1}({\bf z})$? If it contains an element ${\bf x}$, it contains *at least* those ${\bf x'}$'s that are in the orbit $S_n\cdot {\bf x}$ (because the polynomials $e_i$ are symmetric, every element of the orbit $S_n\cdot {\bf x}$ should have the same image under $f$...). It is more difficult to show that each $f^{-1}({\bf z})$ contains exactly one orbit though:

Consider two different orbits $S_n\cdot {\bf x}$ and $S_n\cdot {\bf y}$ and pick a polynomial $\theta\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ such that $\theta({\bf x})=0$ but $\theta({\bf w})\neq 0$ for all ${\bf w}\in S_n\cdot {\bf y}$.  Now consider the polynomial $$\overline{\theta}({\bf w})=\prod_{g\in S_n}\theta(g\cdot{\bf w})$$

By definition, $\overline{\theta}$ is an $S_n$-invariant polynomial that *separates* ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$ (that is, it takes different values on them). Now, [the fundamental theorem of Symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) (see also Theorem 1 below) tells us that $\overline{\theta}$ can be written as a polynomial in the $e_i$'s. In particular, not all the $e_i$'s can agree on ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$, or $\overline{\theta}$ should agree too. This means that ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$ *cannot* be in the same preimage $f^{-1}({\bf z})$ for some ${\bf z}\in \mathbb{C}^n$.

There is one last thing to check; namely, how do we know that for every point ${\bf z}\in \mathbb{C}^n$, the equations $e_i({\bf x})=z_i$ have a common solution? This is because the elementary symmetric functions are exactly $n$-many, and algebraically independent (see also Theorem 2 below). This implies that the system $e_i({\bf x})=z_i$ defines a $(n-n=)\ 0$-dimensional variety, that is, a nonempty, finite set of points. Therefore, every point ${\bf z}\in \mathbb{C}^n$ has a preimage $f^{-1}({\bf z})$ (that has cardinality equal to $n!=|S_n|$ in the generic case).

In this way, the affine space $\mathbb{C}^n$ is *realised* as the quotient $S_n\backslash \mathbb{C}^n$.

This discussion generalizes to all [finite (complex) reflection groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group). The identification between preimages $f^{-1}({\bf z})$ and orbits $G\cdot {\bf x}$ (actually this part holds for any *finite* group $G$ acting linearly on $V$) is given in Chapter 13 of Eisenbud's (very beautiful) book [Commutative Algebra with a view toward algebraic geometry](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1322960). Some of the rest of the arguments are encoded in the two theorems below:

---

**Theorem 1** ([Invariant theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_theory#Introduction)) If a finite group $G$ acts on a polynomial algebra $\mathbb{C}[V]:=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, then the subalgebra $\mathbb{C}[V]^{G}$ is generated by *finitely many* polynomials $f_1,f_2,\cdots, f_m$ (that may however not be algebraically independent).

---

**Theorem 2** ([Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Shephard%E2%80%93Todd_theorem)) In the case (and only then) that $G$ acts as a (finite) (complex) reflection group, the invariant subalgebra $\mathbb{C}[V]^{G}$ is actually a *polynomial* subalgebra. That is, the $f_i$'s are algebraically independent.

---

The reason that these invariant polynomials appear a lot is algebro-geometric: Those are the best candidates for the coordinate ring of the quotient $G\backslash V$ (if that were to be made into a variety). In the case of a finite group $G$ acting linearly on $V$, this happens and is the introduction to [Geometric Invariant Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_invariant_theory#Background).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems like you only show that $f$ is a continuous bijection. How did you show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

I don't think referring to algebraic geometry resolves the issue. Your answer is enough to show that if the quotient is considered scheme-theoretically, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ over $\mathbb{C}$, but I cannot see whether this shows that $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{n}/S_{n}$ when one considers the quotient topology coming from the Euclidean topology.

Comment: The interesting thing is that in complex space, topology quotient (consider quotient analytic topology on $\mathbb C^n/S^n$) coincides with variety quotient (spec of invariant ring). But this does not work over real numbers: the  variety quotient of $\mathbb R^2$ by $\mathbb Z_2$ is still $\mathbb R^2$ (as fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials works over any ring), versus the topological quotient $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z_2$ is half plane with boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I think Theo's answer is valid when you think about the quotient as a scheme. However, if you want to think of the quotient as a topological space whose topology is coming from the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, the situation becomes somewhat different.

The hard part is to show that the inverse of $\mathbb{C}^{n}/S_{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ that Theo gives above is continuous with the topology I mentioned above. It seems that in many places, this is stated but not proved, but some kind people gathered nice proofs, which you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/continuity-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-terms-of-its-coefficients). They seem to be understandable with a first course in complex analysis.

I kept confusing myself by telling me that having an algebraic map between varieties is enough to give a continuous map in the classical Euclidean topology. This does not seem to be the case. However, feel free to let me know if you find a way to resolve this issue algebraically.

Comment: Thanks, I was having precisely this concern, ended up producing a duplicate of this question without knowing of this, and found an answer of yours here :)