# Is this true that the roots of $det(P(x))=0$ are Continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose  ${A_i}\in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}},(i = 0,1,2....m)$ and ${\rm{P(}}x {\rm{) = }}{{\rm{A}}_m}{x ^m} + .....{A_1}x  + {A_0}$ is a matrix polynomial.

Is this true that the roots of $det(P(x))=0$ are Continuous?

Comment: can you clarify the question? $det(P(x))$ is just some polynomial of degree $\leq mn^2$, so as a function in $x$ it is continuous. What do you mean that its roots are continuous?

Comment: What's the purpose of posting questions with *many* different user accounts? If you stick to only one account, you can accumulate reputation points. When you have enough reputation points, you can gain more privileges, such as commenting on other users' postings, editing the others' questions or answers, offer bounties to questions, etc..

Answer (score 1):

$\det P(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$. Now, it is known that the roots of a polynomial vary continuously with the polynomial's coefficients (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/continuity-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-terms-of-its-coefficients)). Hence the roots of the polynomial equation $\det P(x)=0$ vary continuously with the entries of $A_0$ up to $A_m$.