# The roots of a polynomial are a continuous function of the coefficients

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, polynomials

What does the following mean?

> The roots of a polynomial are a ***continuous function of the coefficients***

Please guide me with an example.

Comment: Roughly speaking, it means that "changing a little your polynomial gives you little changes of the roots". I think that this can be totally formalized, but it would be tedious and technical.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/continuity-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-terms-of-its-coefficients

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that given a root $x_0$ of a polynomial $P_0(X)= a_{0,0}+a_{1,0}X++a_{n,0}X^n$, there exits a continuous function $f$ of the coefficents $f(a_0,a_1,...a_n)$, defined in the neigbourhood of $(a_{0,0},...,a_{n,0})$ such that $f(a_0,a_1,...a_n)$ is a root of the polynomial $P(X)=a_{0}+a_{1}X++a_{n}X^n$.

Unfortunately, this theorem is **false** : let $P_0(X)= X^2$ : theres is no continuous function $r(a_0)$ defined in the neigbourhood of $a_{0,0}=0$ such that $r(a_0)^2+a_0=0$ (neither with real nor with complex coefficients)

However such a function exists in the neigbourhood of a simple root, as an immediate application of the implicit function theorem.

Comment: The correct generalization (which works fine for multiple roots) is to take disks of radius $\epsilon>0$ (in $\Bbb C$) around all the roots of $P_0$. Then there is a $\delta>0$ so that if we change the coefficients by less than $\delta$, all the roots of the perturbed polynomial are contained in the union of those disks.

Comment: Certainly, but the roots can also desapear ! In particular the map from the set of polynomials of degree n to the set of finite sets of $\bf C^d$ which send a polynomial to its set of root is not continuous for the Hausdorff topology

Comment: Yes, but my statement is true nevertheless, working with complex polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for the great example. I am still a bit confused here. Given that the roots vary continuously with the parameters https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-01/S0002-9939-1965-0171902-8/S0002-9939-1965-0171902-8.pdf  why can't I define continuous functions mapping coefficients to roots by using the disk definition given in the paper?