# Polynomial roots conditions vary with coefficients

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, permutations

Polynomial equation $\sum_{i=0}^4 p_i x^i=0$ have the following root conditions:

1) $a_0 \pm b_0 i, a_1 \pm b_1i$
2) $a_0 \pm b_0 i, a_1, a_2$
3) $a_0, a_1, a_2 \pm b_2i$
4) $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$

I'm interested in how the root conditions swap with infinitesimal changes in coefficients $p_i$. For instance, condition 1) may change to condition 2) for an infinitesimal change in $p_i$, however, it is unlikely to jump directly to condition 4).

Is there some rules about the permutation of root condition (1-4) with respect to infinitesimal changes of coefficients? The permutations become more tricky when high degree polynomials.

Comment: In $\mathbb C$, roots are continuous functions of the coefficients... Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/continuity-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-terms-of-its-coefficients

Answer (score 2):

In general, this type of problem can be very difficult.  To see some of the difficulties, check out [Wilkinson's Polyonmial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial), specifically, the conditioning and stability parts.

In the case you describe, if you have *real* coefficients, then starting with $4$ distinct real roots, the roots will move continuously as the coefficients vary and remain real *until* two roots coincide, in which case, the roots can split off to a pair of complex conjugates.

Also, your cases $2$ and $3$ are the same since there is no ordering among the roots of a polynomial.