# What kinds of loci do the roots of polynomials give as a coefficient varies- eg $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=o$; for some given values of a,b,c as d varies

Tags: polynomials

When a  coefficient of a polynomial varies , what is the locus of the roots in the Complex Plane?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747486/polynomial-roots-conditions-vary-with-coefficients?rq=1).

Comment: You can "realize" any polynomial as the characteristic polynomial of a certain matrix. This looks artificial, at first view, but it is rather common and  fruitful because much is known on roots which become eigenvalues and their stability. See for example one of my very recent  answers:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2547158

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the parameter $d$ is real.  Then the locus has the implicit equation $\text{Im}((X+iY)^4 + a (X+iY)^3 +b (X+iY)^2 + c (X+iY)) = 0$.

Comment: Dear Teacher and Dear Professor, can you look my problem, if you have few minutes, please. My solution is insufficient, but I dont know what's missing. Can you help/edit my question/solution for me? Best regards. Thank you so much. –

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559814/is-the-proof-i-am-using-sufficient-for-the-system-of-equation