# Slowly changing polynomial equations

Tags: matrices, polynomials, determinant, roots

Is it assured that if we are making only small changes of coefficients in a polynomial equation

$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+... + a_1x +a_0=0$

roots for these equations are changing also by small values? and .. for this case do we have also assured continuity of changes in roots, also in the case when a root is changing from a real value to imaginary one?  (i.e.   function $\mathbf{x}=f(\mathbf{a})$ - where $\mathbf{x}$ is vector of roots $\mathbf{x}= [x_1,x_2,..x_n]^T$ and $\mathbf{a}$  is vector of coefficients $\mathbf{a}= [a_0,a_1,..a_{n-1}]^T$ - is continuous, smooth, makes no great differential changes in values)

- What theorem does describe this situation ?

**Edit (after 9 hours)..**

So far there are no answers...
I wonder whether use of  [Jacobi matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) and [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) for the function $\mathbf{a}=f^{-1}(\mathbf{x})$  would not be a good approach.

---

*Below I'm developing this approach:*

The equation $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+... + a_1x +a_0=0$
 can be written  as

$\mathbf{x}=f(\mathbf{a})$

where $\mathbf{x}$ is vector of roots and $\mathbf{a}$  is vector of coefficients.

In general case it's not easy to obtain function $\mathbf{f}$, but it is possible from Viete'a formulas

$\begin{cases} x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{n-1} + x_n = - {a_{n-1}}   \\ 
(x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3+\cdots + x_1x_n) + (x_2x_3+x_2x_4+\cdots + x_2x_n)+\cdots + x_{n-1}x_n =  {a_{n-2}}   \\
{} \quad \vdots \\ x_1 x_2 \dots x_n = (-1)^n  {a_0}  \end{cases}$

to obtain    function  $g(\mathbf{x}):\ \mathbf{a}=f^{-1}(\mathbf{x}) = g(\mathbf{x}) $ and from this: $  d\mathbf{a}=J(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}$

For this  function we can calculate Jacobi matrix

$\mathbf J = \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{g}}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_n}\\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \dfrac{\partial g_n}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \dfrac{\partial g_n}{\partial x_n} \end{bmatrix}$

$ 
 =\begin{bmatrix}
    \\ (-1)^nx_2 x_3 \dots x_n & \dots &  (-1)^nx_1 x_2 \dots x_{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
  \  x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n & \dots &  x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{n-1} \\
    -1 & \cdots & -1 \end{bmatrix}$

Now the problem is to have finite (and possibly small) $\mathbf {J}^{-1}$     $ \dots$ (we have $  d\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{J}^{-1}(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{a}$)
what is possible only if $det{\mathbf {(J)}}\neq{0}$.

- How to analyze this determinant to get the best results for the starting question?

Comment: Mildly relevant: [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson's_polynomial).

Comment: The roots depend continuously on coefficients, but changes can be quite abrupt, while still mathematically smooth. See for example [Continuity of the roots of a polynomial in terms of its coefficients](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/continuity-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-terms-of-its-coefficients).

Comment: @dxiv very interesting ... thank you...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė It is very relevant, thank you..

Comment: $x^2 + a_1x + a_0$, small $\pm$ changes arount $a_0 = 0$ where $a_1 = 0$?!

Comment: @Pieter21 You mean $x^2+-a_0$ equation ? In this case determinant is equal 0, so changes can't be small..

Comment: Never mind. I was just triggered by the first few words until the first question mark. And apparently roots can also be complex, then I would indeed also expect some continuity in the roots.