# continuity of factorization of differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, continuity

We know that the roots of a complex polynomial are a continuous function of the coefficients of the polynomial. (See for example [this stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/continuity-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-terms-of-its-coefficients) for a discussion.)

Is there a similar continuity for the factorization of a differential operator?

I.e., given a given differential operator like, for example,
$$ \mathcal D = \partial^2 + A(x) \partial + B(x), $$
where $\partial$ is shorthand for $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$, do there exist functions $C(x)$ and $D(x)$ which are (in some appropriate sense) continuously dependent on $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ and such that
$$ \mathcal D = (\partial + C(x))(\partial + D(x)) \quad \textrm{?} $$