# A property of a polynomial whose roots have a stricly negative imaginary part.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $P = a_0 + a_1X + ... + a_nX^n$, such as $\forall k \in$  {$ 0, 2 , .. , n $},  $a_k \in \mathbb{C}$.
Prove that if all roots of P have strictly negative imaginary parts, then :
$R = \operatorname{Re}(a_0) + \operatorname{Re}(a_1)X + ... + \operatorname{Re}(a_n)X^n$  : splits completely over $\mathbb{R}$.
We're dealing with roots here, so I decided to use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) that relate $a_i$'s to the roots.
I tried to prove first that all roots of R are real, but to no avail.
Any ideas?

Comment: For polynomials with real coefficients, it's true that the complex roots come in conjugate pairs. That is, if $a+bi$ is a root, then we know $a-bi$ will also be a root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following method in

- [EVELYN FRANK: ON THE REAL PARTS OF THE ZEROS OF COMPLEX POLYNOMIALS AND APPLICATIONS TO CONTINUED FRACTION EXPANSIONS OF ANALYTIC FUNCTIONS](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1947-062-02/S0002-9947-1947-0021626-6/S0002-9947-1947-0021626-6.pdf)

where it is applied to Hurwitz polynomials. It can be adapted to your problem.

Let $P$ be a complex polynomial whose roots all lie in the lower halfplane. For $0 \le \lambda \le 1$ consider the polynomials
$$
 P_\lambda(z) = P(z) + \lambda \overline{P}(z)
$$
where $\overline{P}$ is obtained from $P$ by replacing all coefficients by their complex conjugates.

We want to show that $P_1$ has only real roots. If that were not the case then $P_1$ must have a root in the upper halfplane.

The roots of $P_\lambda$ are continuous functions of $\lambda$, and all roots of $P_0$ are in the lower halfplane. It follows that there must be a $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ such that $P_\lambda$ has a root on the real axis. But for $x \in \Bbb R$ is $|P(x)| = |\overline{P}(x)|$ and therefore $|P_\lambda(x)| > 0$, so this cannot happen.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the assertion : "the roots of $P_\lambda$ continuous functions of $\lambda$"

Comment: @AymaneLazarus: The roots of a polynomial are continuous functions of the coefficients, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63196/42969. Roughly: Small changes in $\lambda$ cause small changes of the roots of $P_\lambda$.

Comment: Very nice answer!   I am pretty sure you meant $P_{\lambda}(x)\ne 0$ since you get those equal module numbers (conjugate) and $\lambda < 1$.

Comment: @orangeskid Yes, thanks!