# $M_k$ be the set of invertible real $n\times n$ symmetric matrix of index $k$ is open in $\operatorname{Sym}_n(\Bbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, symmetric-matrices

I know that $\forall B\in \operatorname{Sym}_n(\Bbb{R})$, $B$ is orthogonally diagonalizable and also there exists $P\in GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ such that $P^tBP=\operatorname{diag}(-1,\ldots,-1,1,\ldots,1,0\ldots,0)$.

Here index means the number of negative eigenvalues.

Let us denote $A=\operatorname{diag}(-1,\ldots,-1,1\ldots,1)=$ the diagonal matrix with $k$ many $-1$ and $n-k$ many $+1$.

By the above result, it's enough to find a neighborhood of $A$ (say $N$) such that $N\cap \operatorname{Sym}_n(\Bbb{R})\subset M_k$. But I couldn't prove it rigorously.

Can anyone help me to figure that out? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Notice that if you omit the "invertible," this result is false. Do you understand why? So can you make your first sentence more precise in this case?

Comment: If I omit the invertibility condition, then suppose you take a diagonal matrix $B$ of index $k$ with diagonal entries 1,-1 and 0. As I included 0 in the diagonal $B-\epsilon I$ would have index bigger than $k$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. But how to prove the openness of the above set in the question that I am not getting.

Comment: The point is that there are no zeroes. Invertible matrices form an open set in your space. Could the index change in a small open set without crossing out of invertible matrices?

Comment: You are using a subspace topology on $\operatorname{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R})$.  In which space is $N$ an open subset?

Comment: In $\text{Sym}_n (\Bbb{R})$

Answer (score 1):

We use Sylvester's inertia law, the characteristic polynomial $\chi_B$ of $B \in \mathrm{Sym}_n(\mathbb R)$ and the continuity of the roots of polynomials (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63206) for example).

If $\chi_B$ has $p$ positive roots, $q$ negative roots, then there is $\epsilon >0$ such that if $\|C-B\| < \epsilon$ and $C\in\mathrm{Sym}_n(\mathbb R)$, $\chi_C$ has $\geq p$ positive roots and $\geq q$ positive roots. If $B$ has a zero eigenvalue, then it can become positive or negative arbitrarily close from $B$ so we do not have equality. However, if $B$ is invertible, $p+q =n$, and we see that any $C\in \mathrm{Sym}_n(\mathbb R)$ with $\|B-C\| <\epsilon$ has exactly $p$ positive eigenvalues and $q$ negative eigenvalues.

Comment: You need Sylvester's law of inertia, as well, if you take this approach. You need to know that the index of the symmetric bilinear form is equal precisely to the number of negative eigenvalues of the associated linear map.

Comment: True, thanks for the feedback !