# Continuity of roots of polynomials in non-archimedean local field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

**Statement:** Let $K$ be a non-archimedean local field. Let $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0 \in K[x]$ be a monic polynomial and let $a \in K$ be a simple root of $f$.  Let $g(x)=x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots+b_0$ be another monic polynomial in $K[x]$. Show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a root $b \in K$ of $g$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|a_i-b_i|< \delta$ for $i=0, \dots, n-1$ implies $|a-b|< \epsilon$.

**My try:** I have tried ideas which are similar to an answer given by Pete L. Clark in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63218 to a slightly different problem. He references this (http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Math8410Ex3.17David.pdf) solution, which I copy here ($\beta \in \overline{K}$ is an arbitrary root of $g$):$$|f(\beta)|=|f(\beta)-g(\beta)|\leq \sum_{i=0}^{n} |a_i-b_i|^i< \delta \sum_{i=0}^n M^i<\epsilon^n,$$ where (taking $a_n=1$)$$M=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(1+2|a_i| \right), \hspace{1cm} N=\max\left(1, \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|a_i|\right), \hspace{1cm} \delta<\min\left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{\epsilon^n}{\sum_{i=0}^n M^i}, \frac{\epsilon^n}{2\sum_{i=0}^n N^i}\right).$$
Then, if we write $f=(x-\alpha_1) \cdot \dots \cdot (x-\alpha_n)$ for some $\alpha_i \in \overline{K}$ (the algebraic closure of $K$), it follows that, for an arbitrary root $\beta \in \overline{K}$ of $g$, $\prod_{i=1}^n |\beta-\alpha_i| < \epsilon^n$, and so $|\beta-\alpha_i|<\epsilon$ for some $i \in \lbrace 1, \dots, n \rbrace$.
Let $\alpha \in \overline{K}$ be an arbitrary root of $f$. Then, $|g(a)| <\delta \sum_{i=0}^n N^i<\frac{\epsilon^n}{2}<\epsilon^n$, so $|\alpha - \beta|< \epsilon$ for some root $\beta$ of $g$.

**My problem with this try:** The problem is a bit different since we did not assume that $a$ was a simple root of $f$ above. Also, it does not prove that the desired $b \in \overline{K}$ is actually in $K$. I have been told that instead it is possible to try to copy the argument of the proof of Hensel's lemma. The steps would be roughly as follows:

**Different try I do not fully understand:**

Step 1. Assume, without loss of generality, that $f, g \in \mathcal{O}[x]$, where $\mathcal{O}=\lbrace x \in K \ | \ |x| \leq 1 \rbrace$. Write $g(a+x)=g(a)+g'(a)x+y$ with $|y| \leq |x|^2$.

Step 2. Let $N>\nu\ (f'(a))=k$, where $\nu$ is the discrete valuation. Assume, by the triangular inequality, that $\omega^N \ | \ g-f$, where $\omega$ is a uniformizer. Then, $g'(a) \neq 0$. In fact, $\nu\ (g'(a))=\nu\ (f'(a))$. We have $\omega^N \ | \ g(a). $ (Why is this true?)

Step 3. Take $g$ even closer to $f$ and assume $\omega^{2k+2} \ | \ g(a)$. Solve $g(a+x) \equiv 0 \mod \omega^{2k+2},$ with $x \in \omega^{k+1} \mathcal{O}$. This leads to $g(a)+g'(a)x \equiv 0 \mod \omega^{2k+2}$, and $x=-\frac{g(a)}{g'(a)} \in \omega^{k+1} \mathcal{O}$. This way, we can find $x_0 \in \omega^{k+1}, x_1 \in \omega^{k+2}, \dots$ and this converges. (I think here we use that $\mathcal{O} \cong  \varprojlim \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^n$, and we define $b=(x_0, \dots, x_n, \dots)$.)

Summary I have been provided: $g \in \mathcal{O}[x]$. $a \in \mathcal{O}$. $|g(a)| < |g'(a)|^2$. Then $\exists b \in \mathcal{O}$ such that $g(b)=0$.

**My questions:**

Question 1: In the setting of the first try I have referenced above, can one prove that $b \in K$ if $a$ is a simple root of $f$? They always work with extensions of $K$ as far as I can tell.

Question 2: How does the second try exactly relate to the proof of Hensel's lemma? (I am following the one in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, p.129)

Question 3: Why can we assume in Step 3 of the second try that $\omega^N \ | \ g(a)$? Also why does previously the triangular inequality imply that $\omega^N \ | \ f-g$ without loss of generality? I do not understand what is the role of $N$ and why we compare it to $\nu \ (f'(a))$.

Question 4: Why exactly does the sequence in Step 3 converge? Is this the same as the argument of the proof of Hensel's lemma?

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Given $g(b)=0$. If the coefficients of $g$ are very close to those of $f$ then $v(f(b))=v(f(b)-g(b))$ is large.

Write $f=\prod_{j=1}^n (x-a_j)$, $v(f(b))=\sum_{j=1}^n v(b-a_j)$.
Conclude by saying that one of the $v(b-a_j)$ must be $\ge \frac{v(f(b))}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @reuns. This proves that $b$ is close to some $a_j$, but why does it follow that $b \in K$?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't notice you asked for Krasner lemma. Yes you need (generalized) Hensel lemma, if $v(g(a))$ is large enough then doing a gradient descent $u_{m+1} = u_m-G(u_m)/G'(u_m)$ starting from $u_0=a$ will converge to a root of $g$ (where $G=g/\gcd(g,g')$ to make it separable)

Comment: Thank you very much for the further answer @reuns. I have proved it converges to a root of $g$ in $K$.
Is the separability condition to avoid dividing by zero in the process?

On the other hand, I have found the following version of Krasner's lemma in Lang's ANT (Proposition 3, p.43):
Let $\alpha, \beta \in \overline{K}$, with $\alpha$ separable over $K(\beta)$. Assume for all isomorphisms $K(\alpha)$ over $K$, $\sigma \neq \text{Id}$, we have $|\beta-\alpha|<|\sigma \alpha - \alpha|$. Then $K(\alpha) \subset K(\beta)$.

Could this be used in this exercise as well and claim $b \in K$?